# Greasemonkey - replacing one div with another

Tags: greasemonkey

I have a website with a div that looks like this:

```
      <div id="j_id241:0:j_id269:2:j_id284:0:j_id289" class="number">Current data</div>
```

And I'd like to replace it with something like:

```
    <div id="j_id241:0:j_id269:2:j_id284:0:j_id289" class="number">Replacement data</div>
```

The current data changes regularly, so I'd rather replace the div itself than do a search and replace for the text.

Is this possible?

Comment: That `id` does not look stable.  **How do you know which div to change?**

Comment: I don't have control of the page itself, so I'm working with what I have.  The ID appears to remain the same over time.  But I can't get Greasemonkey to see it.